# Is a lone linefeed (0x0A) a violation of the INI format?

Tags: android, ini, ini4j

Is it a violation if the INI format to have a single linefeed (0x0A) that is ***not*** preceded by a carraige return (0x0D)?

[Ini4j](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net) is puking on this in my Android app.

Please abstain from asking *why* I'm using INI in an Android app...

Comment: Why are you using INI in an Android app? Oups, I did it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `*.ini` is a windows format, you can expect, that each newline must be `\r\n`.

At least in the sources, only the `Registry` class definitivly relies on `\r\n`. In all other cases it seems, as if the system property `line.separator` is used.

It's still arguable is a cross-plattform library should rely on it...

---

The problem can be resolved setting `setEmptyOption(true)` e.g.

```
Config c = new Config();
c.setEmptyOption(true);
Ini i = new Ini();
i.setConfig(c);
```

Comment: Setting `line.separator` one way or the other doesn't seem to help.

Comment: ini4j has a configuration setting `setEmptyOption()`, which we switched to `true`. That cleared up the problem - at least for the time being.

Comment: can you specify the exact change, so I can update my answer if anyone else has the same problem? I can't tell where `setEmptyOption()` is.

Comment: The method is `org.ini4j.Config.setEmptyOption()`. You use it via `Config c = new Config(); c.setEmptyOption(true); Ini i = new Ini(); i.setConfig(c);`